# How to execute javascript in jmeter generating some sessionID which is used in subsequent requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, jmeter

I'm not able to correlate the value of " **bpmWAPISessionId** " which needs to accompany subsequent requests.  But this values does not appear in any of the responses in Jmeter. i'm able to identify using "Fiddler" that the value is getting generated as a part of a Javascript execution.  Below is the output from Fiddler showing Javascript execution setting the " **bpmWAPISessionId** " value:

XPAjaxResponse ts="1411375385977"  tag start ######

Javascript Tag start #########

![CDATA[var dialogTitle = document.getElementById('workspace-1930287331991992370__id2_menuActionNormalMode242_executionDialogView242_executionDialog242_242_Title');if(dialogTitle != null){dialogTitle.innerHTML='UPDF Process - Test Creation';};executeDialog242("/workspace/servlet/executor?actionType=0&activityId=%2FUPDFProcess%23Default-9.0%2FUPDFProcessTestCreation&ts=379964413368670&**bpmWAPISessionId**=877732603&executionType=DIALOG&portletId=242", "/UPDFProcess#Default-9.0/UPDFProcessTestCreation");]]>

Javascript Tag End #######

XPAjaxResponse tag end ######

Is there any mechanism to execute Javascript in Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

By design Jmeter can not handle any AJAX/Javascript calls.

There is a way to achieve the above scenario, by manually creating an Http sampler & making a direct call to the URL with necessary parameters to generate the SessionID.

you can use firebug to get the request details which happens inside the AJAX call for sessionID generation.

Hope this will help.

Comment: actually the request is in .xhtml format and response is in  XPAjaxResponse format after adding manual http sampler still same issue persist. according to my question thread i'm able to see response in fidler but not in view result tree in jmeter

Comment: this is the workaround I have been implementing all around. Jmeter and fiddler are different. As I have mentioned above jmeter will not handle AJAX calls. 
implementation of the workaround is up to you, since you know the application & I don't.